# How can I plot from hdf4 file using Python

Tags: python, hdf

I have downloaded MODIS land use land cover data.The key name of the data product is MCD12C1.Now I want to plot/visualize different land use land cover data on map using python.`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import rioxarray
import rasterio as rio
from osgeo import gdal
import earthpy as et
import earthpy.spatial as es
import earthpy.plot as ep 

title='c:/MCD12C1.A2022001.061.2023244164746'
all_bands=[]
with rio.open(f'{title}.HDF') as dataset:
    hdf4_meta = dataset.meta 
    crs = dataset.read_crs()

    for layer_name in [name for name in dataset.subdatasets]:
        print(layer_name)
        with rio.open(layer_name) as subdataset:
            modis_meta = subdataset.profile
            all_bands.append(subdataset.read(1))
```

I have written the above code.After this how to proceed ?
`

Comment: I'd suggest you have a look at [cartopy](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy), [eomaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps) or the [rasterio section on plotting](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/plotting.html)

Comment: I tried with rasterio.But it is not working.The program is running.But it is not showing any plot.I dont know what is the issue.

Comment: Without the data it's hard to see where things go wrong...  If you share the hdf file i can show you how you can plot it with eomaps.

Comment: It is a large file.Size is around 1gb.The data is available in NASA USGS website.From there in data set option there is an option named NASA LPDAAC collection.Under that option MODIS Land Cover V6.1 option is there.Under this option the product MCD12C1 is located.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that the data is quite large and your script will take ages to finish reading... what you want is to open the file lazily and then  only select what you really need!

I'd suggest that you have a look at [rioxarray](https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray) (the rasterio-extension for `xarray`) and load the data with `chunks=True` so that the file is loaded as a lazy `dask` dataset.

Then you can easily pre-select the data and only load what you really need.

Something like this should do the job:

```py
import rioxarray as rxr

file = rxr.open_rasterio(
    "MCD12C1.A2022001.061.2023244164746.hdf", 
    chunks=True # use dask to avoid loading the data immediately
)
df = file.Majority_Land_Cover_Type_1.sel(band=1)

# trigger loading the data
# coordinates
x = df.x.to_numpy()
y = df.y.to_numpy()

# data-values (transposed as required by eomaps)
data = df.to_numpy().T

file.close()
```

Once you have your dataset loaded, you can plot it with [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps) like this:

I use `m.set_shape.raster(maxsize=1e5)` to visualize the data as a 2D raster, pre-aggregated to ~1e5 datapoints (in total it's ~26 million) prior to plotting.

```py
from eomaps import Maps

m = Maps()
m.set_data(data, x, y, crs = df.spatial_ref.crs_wkt)
m.set_shape.raster(maxsize=1e5, aggregator="median")
m.plot_map(cmap="viridis")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time.It works.Can you tell me how to extract the lat/lon of the points where it is  ,for example:"savana".I am very new to work with hdf files.So I'm facing a lot of problems reading the data.

Comment: Since it seems to work, how about accepting it as answer then?
Concerning your question... I guess you first have to find out what value represents "savanna" in your `data` array and then use something like `np.where(data==savanna_value)` to get the x-y indexes you're searching for...

Comment: Your code is working fine.But it is taking some times to run.So I used gdal.It is working much quicker.                                
The value for croplands is 12.But the coordinates are confusing to understand.                [127,  127,  127, ..., 3526, 3526, 3527]                                                                               [2913, 2914, 2915, ...,  648,  660,  410]     
When I plot the whole data it is showing same as your plot with x co0rdinates value showing from 0 to 7000 from left to right and y coordinate is showing 0 to 3500 from top to bottom

Comment: If my question is difficult to understand What I'm trying to stay then I can post a separate question with my code and output on this website and mention you.I'll be very grateful if you answer the question.

Comment: If you check the docs for `np.where(condition)` you'll find that it returns the indexes of non-zero values... (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where) either provide the arrays you want to select from to the function or use the returned index-arrays to select your coordinates from `lon` and `lat`!

Comment: Actually it is giving the index of grid points.The data array is 3600*7200.Then how to convert this grid points to standard lat lon?

Comment: well, in my example code above, the coordinate vectors are loaded as `x=...` and `y=...`. So `x_savanna = x[savanna_x_indexes]` should do the job. If this is not enough, please post a separate question (incl.code where you get stuck) to avoid lengthy discussions in the comments.

Comment: I've posted a separate question.                                                                                           https://stackoverflow.com/q/78139863/23295780