# How to find lat/lon in MODIS data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, rasterio

I plotted the MODIS land use land cover data.But the coordinates are showing as grid index.I converted this to lat/lon value.But the plot is upside down.What is the solution for this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rioxarray
import rasterio as rio
from osgeo import gdal
f='MCD12C1.A2022001.061.2023244164746.HDF'
ds = gdal.Open(f)
datasets_meta = ds.GetMetadata("SUBDATASETS")
major_lnd_cvr_1 = gdal.Open(datasets_meta['SUBDATASET_1_NAME'])
major_lnd_cvr_1_array = major_lnd_cvr_1.ReadAsArray()
plt.imshow(major_lnd_cvr_1_array)
major_lnd_cvr_1_meta = major_lnd_cvr_1.GetMetadata()
img=plt.contourf(np.arange(-180,180,0.05), np.arange(-90,90,0.05),major_lnd_cvr_1_array)
```

[image]

Comment: transpose the data